# postgresql - define serial data type in java project

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, playframework, playframework-2.0

I use play! framework 2.0 and postgresql.
in my db there is users table and every user ofcourse has a unique id.
so I defined it as `serial`.

my question is: how to represent a field which it's data type is `serial`
in my java project.

p.s. I understood play! framework uses Hibernate annotation

Comment: `serial` is "just" an integer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL), the `SERIAL` type is equivalent to an ìnteger` with a sequence, so:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    colname SERIAL
);
```

is equivalent to specifying:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq;
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    colname integer DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq') NOT NULL
);
```

The `@Id` JPA annotation on the `Long` type will provide a sequence (equivalent to `AUTO_INCREMENT` in MySQL).

So, in you class, just use:

```
@Id
public Long id;
```

Answer (score 0):

OK. I just added the annotation `@Id`